# "×" shows up as "Ч" Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

In Chrome, × (multiplication sign) often shows up as a Ч(che) :

[image: che?]

Copying it and in page source it is × . How might I fix this?

I have:

1. Diabled extensions
2. Switched browsers (cannot reproduce in Firefox)
3. Changed encoding from UTF-8 to multiple others.
4. Disabled JavaScript

But still the annoying problem persists.

Comment: have you tried the same site in another browser too?

Comment: @MátéJuhász On Firefox it shows up correctly but shows up as che in IE 11. It also shows up as `~W` in lynx.

Comment: Can you link us the site? It could be a case where somewhere in the HTML its set to use this specific unicode.

Comment: @LPChip http://www.chemistryexplained.com/Ma-Na/Mole-Concept.html . However, it isn't limited to the site.

Comment: @LPChip Thanks for helping, every site experiencing this uses Bootstrap and blocking Bootstrap solves it. I think asking on StackOverflow would help.

Comment: @MátéJuhász Thanks for helping, it's caused by Bootstrap :)

Comment: Good to hear that you found it. You can post an answer yourself and mark it as solved in 2 days. Could you do that for us, so others know you no longer need any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every website that has this issue uses Bootstrap, and blocking `Bootstrap.CSS`stops it. It's not a solution, but might help others diagnose.